# How Do I Access an Object's Properties From a Template?

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

According to http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html, I should be able to do this:

```
<h1>{{article.title}}</h1>
```

But I can't seem to get this to work in meteor. Here's my template:

```
<template name="content">
  {{#if item}}
    <p>{{item.name}}</p>
  {{/if}}
</template>
```

Here's the JavaScript that returns the item:

```
  Template.content.item = function() {
    return Items.findOne({ _id: Session.get("list_id") });
  };
```

And yes, the item does indeed have a property called `name` :-)

When I do this, I see an error in Firebug that says `ret is undefined`

This can be tracked down to evaluate.js:

```
for (var i = 1; i < id.length; i++)
  // XXX error (and/or unknown key) handling
  ret = ret[id[i]];
return ret;
```

At the moment of the error, `ret` references the `window` object. What's up with that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should use {{#with object}}

If your object is something like :

```
my_object = {
    name : 'my_name',
    prop : 'my_prop'
}
```

In your template your can do :

```
<template name="my_template">
    {{#with my_object}}
        <p>Name is {{name}}<p>
        <p>Prop is {{prop}}</p>
    {{/with}}
</template>
```

Here you go :)

Comment: I'll just add to this that using the http://tryHandlebarsjs.com site (paste in some JSON and your template) can be one of the fastest ways to figure out what's going wrong in this case. Then you're just focused on your template and the data in the absence of anything else that can go wrong.

Comment: @Paperwork: Thanks again. I was wondering what the delay was, and now it appears that my question inspired you to sign up for StackOverflow, so I guess we've both done a good deed today :-)

Comment: But how to use {{#with object}} only when a property of object is truthy?