# Handlebars.js own helpers

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I don't understand how can I get the data from registered helper. 
I have the code in global place:

```
var options = {'foo': 'Bar'};
Handlebars.registerHelper('options', function(){return options;});
```

In template I'm try to calling options

```
{{#with options}}{{foo}}{{/with}}
```

In the template I got the [Object object] on the output. Where is the mistake?

I have the options not in JSON. In the JSON I am sending the dynamical data, but the options is static and I keep this in JS file and I need to call the options object in the template file. How can I do this?

Upd:
I am loading the template into div by using jQuery. The script adding the data to the template. I need to get access to global variable(where the template calls). Not in template, not in JSON, only in global place. So, the JSON data can be empty.
Upd2:
Global place:

```
<script src="handlebars.js">
<script>
var options = {foo: 'Foo', bar: 'Bar'};
var getTemplate = function(data) {
 return $.get('/static/templates/' + data.tpl + '.html').then(function(src) {
    return Handlebars.compile(src)(data);
});}
//run getTemplate()
</script>
```

Template file:

```
{{#with options}}{{foo}}{{/with}}
```

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234725/accessing-an-objects-properties-from-a-template

Comment: But short answer: use a `{{#with options}}` blocks.

Comment: You don't need to. Check out the first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10236319/2456258

Comment: I have var options = {foo: 'Bar'}; and i'm trying to use  {{#with options}}{{foo}}{{/with}}. It doesn't works

Comment: Then *update your question* with what you've tried. Right now, your question as written is a duplicate that has a valid answer.

Comment: I mean global place. I am loading the template into div by using jQuery. The script adding the data to the template. I need to get access to global variable(where the template calls). Not in template, not in JSON, only in global place. So, the JSON data can be empty.