# Access Object property from template in handlebars

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js, helper

According the documentation and to this link [Stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10234725/how-do-i-access-an-objects-properties-from-a-template), i should be able to access the property of my object, but it doesent work. Here is my code-snipped.

Handlebars helper

```
var person ={
    name : "test"
};

Handlebars.registerHelper('getperson', function() {
    console.log(person.name);
    return person;
```

Template

```
<h1>{{ getperson }} </h1>
```

In this constellation i get rendered: **[object Object]**

but i want to display the persons name "test"

```
{{#with getperson}}
    <h1< {{name}} </h1>
{{/with}}
```

This snipped didnt work for me. :-(

Answer (score 0):

Some mistakes to my mind :

First use this structure so person is something you can name :

```
var context = { "person" : { name : "test" , id : "id" } };
```

Second use this template : the helper will use person from your structure:

```
<div class="data-container">
{{#getperson person}}
{{/getperson}}
</div>
```

Third your helper can use now the argument that you passed:

```
  Handlebars.registerHelper('getperson', function(data, options) {
    var out = "<h1>" + data.name + "</h1><br/><h2>"  + data.id  + "</h2>"; 
    console.log(out);
    return out;
  });
```

You can find the full working example here :

https://jsfiddle.net/ChristopheThiry/eorkkrts/

Edit: updated to match the fiddle with the new requirement of having multiple data fields.

Comment: thank you for the jsfiddle example. The Problem is, i want to access much more properties. I need to return a whole object from my helper not only one property.

Comment: I've updated the fiddle, is that an example more convenient for you ?

Comment: in my real app i need access to a lot of object-properties at diferent positions and the outer Html-Elements can change dynamically. But if this is the only solution, i will build the html in the helpers method. Thx. :)

Comment: Yes sorry I don't have something better to propose.